CodeChecker store command error : Thrift invalid data error. How is it caused?
I have a codechecker web (UI) container running at codechecker.XX.de.
I have configured user using the server-config.json [for eg: user XX:XX, username XX, password XX]
I created a product for the UI: example-cpp
I want to store the results of one of the analysis that I did on to the UI.
I tried the following:
CodeChecker cmd login XX
--->login successful

CodeChecker store /codechecker/results --name example --url http://codechecker.XX.de/example-cpp


Response:
[INFO 2024-05-07 13:41] - Storing analysis results for run 'example'
[INFO 2024-05-07 13:41] - Checking local passwords or tokens in /root/.codechecker.passwords.json
[WARNING 2024-05-07 13:41] - '/root/.codechecker.passwords.json' is readable by users other than you! This poses a risk of leaking sensitive information, such as passwords, session tokens, etc.!
Please 'chmod 0600 /root/.codechecker.passwords.json' so only you can access the file.
[INFO 2024-05-07 13:41] - Checking for local valid sessions.
[ERROR 2024-05-07 13:41] - Thrift invalid data error.
[ERROR 2024-05-07 13:41] - getAuthParameters
[ERROR 2024-05-07 13:41] - []
[ERROR 2024-05-07 13:41] - {}
[ERROR 2024-05-07 13:41] - Request failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/codechecker/lib/python3/codechecker_client/thrift_call.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/codechecker_api/Authentication_v6/codeCheckerAuthentication.py", line 162, in getAuthParameters
    return self.recv_getAuthParameters()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/codechecker_api/Authentication_v6/codeCheckerAuthentication.py", line 173, in recv_getAuthParameters
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TJSONProtocol.py", line 417, in readMessageBegin
    self.readJSONArrayStart()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TJSONProtocol.py", line 405, in readJSONArrayStart
    self.readJSONSyntaxChar(LBRACKET)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TJSONProtocol.py", line 255, in readJSONSyntaxChar
    raise TProtocolException(TProtocolException.INVALID_DATA,
thrift.protocol.TProtocol.TProtocolException: Unexpected character: b'<'


Any suggestions are welcome here.

CodeChecker dev here. I know this is an old question, but if anyone gets here, this might help him.
It is difficult to say what is wrong here, without seeing your stack configuration. From the error in the last line Unexpected character: b'<'  I suspect your proxy is returning some HTTP error code, instead of a proper Codechecker thrift answer, and the CodeChecker client cannot parse it.
